# Books about modal logic?

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, philosophy, modal-logic

I've just approached modal logic reading "An Introduction to Non-Classical Logic" of Graham Priest.

I am looking for some books that treat this argument in a more extensive way than the book I am reading.
I am especially interested in the philosophical  side of modal logic.

Can you suggest me some books?

Answer (score 7):

Here are a few recommendations for you, all with an emphasis on the philosophical aspects of modal logic:

["Modal Logic for Philosophers"](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=xFNbDZPZERcC&printsec=frontcover&dq=modal%20logic&hl=en&sa=X&ei=c8UFUuaiB8eHkgWKtoGYAg&ved=0CEUQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=modal%20logic&f=false) (Garson, 2006).

["Modal Logics and Philosophy"](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=hExvQnfMvA8C&dq=modal%20logic&hl=en&sa=X&ei=_MUFUp3BGozvkgX284CwBg&ved=0CFsQ6AEwCDgK) (Girle, 2000).

["Handbook of Philosophical Logic, Volume 14"](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=b-NdnFrX-CcC&printsec=frontcover&dq=modal%20logic%20philosophy&hl=en&sa=X&ei=iMYFUpvFL8u3kAXoooGoCg&ved=0CEAQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=modal%20logic%20philosophy&f=false) (Gabbay and Geunthener eds, 2007).

["Modal Logic: 
An Introduction to Its Syntax and Semantics"](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=82jvmAEACAAJ&dq=modal%20logic&hl=en&sa=X&ei=BMcFUprXOIn_lAWRroDwCA&ved=0CEMQ6AEwBDgy) (Cocchiarella and Freund, 2008)

I hope these help.

Answer (score 7):

I personally learned modal logic from Chellas's [Modal Logic: An Introduction](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521295157), but a more modern treatment in-line with current interests in modal logic is van Benthem's [Modal Logic for Open Minds](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/157586598X). Other good introductions include [Modal Logic: An Introduction to its Syntax and Semantics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0195366573), Cresswell & Hughes's [A New Introduction to Modal Logic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0415126002), and Beall & van Fraassen's [Possibilities and Paradox: An Introduction to Modal and Many-Valued Logic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0199259879). Also, take a look at the SEP article on [Modal Logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-modal/) (SEP is in general a great place to skim through the bibliographies for references on various philosophical topics, including philosophical and mathematical logic).

Answer (score 1):

https://www.elsevier.com/books/handbook-of-modal-logic/blackburn/978-0-444-51690-9

Patrick Blackburn Johan van Benthem Frank Wolte

https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/modal-logic/F7CDB0A265026BF05EAD1091A47FCF5B#

Patrick Blackburn, Maarten de Rijke, Universiteit van Amsterdam , Yde Venema, Universiteit van Amsterdam

https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4020-5587-4_5

Johan van Benthem, Guram Bezhanishvili